# Creating different shelvesets for different work itesm without checking-in TFVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I have a couple of work items which I need to complete but my code reviewer is unavailable. I was wondering if it is possible address each work item separately and shelve the changes for code review later. i.e Assuming i have 3 work items A and B. Is it possible to work on Work Item A, shelve the changes then work on Work Item B and shelve the changes. Then at a later date, send the shelvesets for A and B for code review

Comment: Not sure I understand. When you create a shelfset, you can select which files they contain. Do you mean that you are having to make changes to the same source files for work item A *and* work item B? If so, you might need to make one branch for each work item, and then merge the changes back into the main branch after the code review is accepted. (And then delete the branch)

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Yes, I am having to make changes to the same source files for work Item A and B. I will look into what you said. I have experience with Git and ever since i moved over to TFVC, I have just been confused.

Comment: nim's answer should work for you.

Comment: @David Have you tried the suggestion mentioned in nim's answer? any update here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you have 2 work items that both need to touch the same file(s). If you are using a recent version Visual Studio, then you have the option to "Preserve pending changes locally" upon creation of the shelveset (checkbox immediately below the field where you enter the name for the shelveset).

Provided you only work on change at a time, you could:

1. Make changes for work item A
2. Create shelveset a, and not preserve changes locally
3. Make changes for work item B
4. Create shelveset b, and not preserve changes locally

If you aren't using Visual Studio, the same could be accomplished by making the changes and shelveset for A, and then locally revert those changes, putting things back to their initial state, and then work on B.

All of this assumes the changes for both A and B aren't currently all made together touching the same files...

p.s. I would have added a comment to the thread above, but i don't have enough points to do so.